# Regex pattern to replace a string

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I have the following input:

```
Person 1kg
```

To get the expected output:

```
Person 1kEq
```

I am using the following pattern:

```
string.Format(@"(?<!\S){0}(?!\S)", Regex.Escape("kg"));
Regex.Replace(inputSentence, Pattern, "kEq");
```

The `Regex.Replace` does not replace `kg` with `kEq`.

If I edit the input sentence to `Person 1 kg` the replacement happens,

Could someone help me with the pattern for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `(?<!\S)` requires either a start of the string or a whitespace before the `kg` search term. The `(?!\S)` lookahead requires the end of string or a whitespace after the search term. That is why the replacement happens if you separate the number and the measurement unit with a space as in `Person 1 kg`.

It seems in this case, you want to replace a match if it is not enclosed with other *letters*. Use `(?<!\p{L})` lookbehind at the start and `(?!\p{L})` lookahead at the end:

```
string.Format(@"(?<!\p{{L}}){0}(?!\p{{L}})", Regex.Escape("kg"));
```

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3f%3c!%5cp%7bL%7d%29kg%28%3f!%5cp%7bL%7d%29&i=Person+1kg&r=kEq).

Comment: I get a FormatException when I use this above pattern/C# statement, could you please help me out?

Comment: Sorry, I always remember to double the curly braces with limiting quantifiers, and forgot to do the same with the Unicode category class.